# Xcode Video Transparent Background

Tags: xcode, video, transparent

As title says i stucked with video transparent. I have videos with no background on After Effects. I m trying to export in .mov format my video with all codecs that are inside my AE but videos dont play. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you give further details on how you're doing? I.e. a code snippet on how you're displaying the video.

Comment: I tried to use all codecs, aplle, animation etc. Im playing the video with moviePlayer as .mov file